# Jquery form submission still refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to add ajax form submission to a PHP web app I'm working on using jquery. The form is being submitted and writing to a database, but it'll still doing it all with a refresh.

Here's my code:

```
$("form#form_customer").submit(function() {
            var customer123first_name = $('input[name=customer123first_name.]');
            var customer123last_name = $('input[name=customer123last_name.]');
            var customer123date_of_birth = $('input[name=customer123date_of_birth.]');
            var customer123email_address = $('input[name=customer123email_address.]');
            var customer123telephone_number = $('input[name=customer123telephone_number.]');
            var customer123picture = $('input[name=customer123picture.]');
            var customer123id_picture = $('input[name=customer123id_picture.]');
            var customer123id_expiration = $('input[name=customer123id_expiration.]');
            var data = 'customer123first_name=' + customer123first_name.val() + '&customer123last_name=' + customer123last_name.val() + '&customer123date_of_birth=' + customer123date_of_birth.val() + '&customer123email_address=' + customer123email_address.val() + '&customer123telephone_number=' + customer123telephone_number.val() + '&customer123picture=' + customer123picture.val() + '&customer123id_picture=' + customer123id_picture.val() + '&customer123id_expiration=' + customer123id_expiration.val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "inc/createObject.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('form_success').fadeIn();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Everything I've read online for this specific issue has found the `return false;` call to be in the wrong place or not there at all. I've checked mine is in the right place, I just can't find a reason why it's refreshing.

I know jquery is working because I use it to do popups windows which are working fine.

If you want to see the code in context, go to www.sfyfe.com/studioadmin

Comment: `$('form_success').fadeIn();` here is the mistake? what element you're referring to? It's either id `#` or class `.` or html element?

Comment: on customer dialog are you getting this error ? Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=customer123first_name.]Source File: http://www.sfyfe.com/studioadmin/js/jquery.jsLine: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the dot at the end of the selector on your `$('input[name=customer123...` lines. The dot isn't doing anything, and it's making the selector invalid. Removing the dots should fix the problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
$("form#form_customer").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: He already has `return false;`, which calls `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the data in JSON format ,  using :  " data : data " is not valid , 
try:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "inc/createObject.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{dataField : data },
```

Comment: I did this, but it stopped inserting to the MySQL database. Changing it back to "data: data," fixed that.

Comment: This is the right format , and in the PHP file you should use  $var = $_POST['dataField']

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this.

```
$("form#form_customer").submit(function() {
            var customer123first_name = $('input[name=customer123first_name]');
            var customer123last_name = $('input[name=customer123last_name]');
            var customer123date_of_birth = $('input[name=customer123date_of_birth]');
            var customer123email_address = $('input[name=customer123email_address]');
            var customer123telephone_number = $('input[name=customer123telephone_number]');
            var customer123picture = $('input[name=customer123picture]');
            var customer123id_picture = $('input[name=customer123id_picture]');
            var customer123id_expiration = $('input[name=customer123id_expiration]');
            var data = 'customer123first_name=' + customer123first_name.val() + '&customer123last_name=' + customer123last_name.val() + '&customer123date_of_birth=' + customer123date_of_birth.val() + '&customer123email_address=' + customer123email_address.val() + '&customer123telephone_number=' + customer123telephone_number.val() + '&customer123picture=' + customer123picture.val() + '&customer123id_picture=' + customer123id_picture.val() + '&customer123id_expiration=' + customer123id_expiration.val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "inc/createObject.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('form_success').fadeIn();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```